# Forcing clang to emit pmull2/umull2 variants of opcodes

Tags: assembly, compiler-optimization, arm64, neon

I have this (and similar) pieces of code where I expect umull2 or pmull2 instructions to be emitted. Compiler clang-11.0.1, options `-O3 -std=c++11 -target aarch64`

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "arm_neon.h"
inline poly16x8_t vmull_low_p8(poly8x16_t a, poly8x16_t b) {
    return vmull_p8(vget_low_p8(a), vget_low_p8(b));
}
// evaluates polynomials of length `len > 0` using Horner's method
// for 16 points `x`, `X = x 2^m mod n`
poly16x8x2_t p(const uint8_t *input, int len, poly8x16_t x, poly8x16_t X) {
    auto ptr = input + len;
    auto L = vdupq_n_p16(*--ptr), H = L;
    while (ptr > input) {
        auto s = vuzpq_p8(vreinterpretq_p8_p16(L), vreinterpretq_p8_p16(H));
        auto a = vmull_low_p8(s.val[0], x);
        auto b = vmull_high_p8(s.val[0], x);
        auto A = vmull_low_p8(s.val[1], X);
        auto B = vmull_high_p8(s.val[1], X);
        auto C = vdupq_n_p16(*--ptr);
        L = C ^ a ^ A;
        H = C ^ b ^ B;
    }
    return {L,H};
}
```

Instead of having code like

```
    ldrb    w9, [x8, #-1]!
    uzp1    v6.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b
    uzp2    v2.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b
    pmull   v3.8h, v6.8b, v0.8b
    pmull2  v7.8h, v6.8b, v0.8b
    pmull   v6.8h, v6.8b, v4.8b
    pmull2  v2.8h, v2.8b, v4.8b
```

the compiler has chosen to

```
    ldrb    w9, [x8, #-1]!
    uzp1    v6.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b
    uzp2    v2.16b, v2.16b, v3.16b
    pmull   v3.8h, v6.8b, v0.8b
    ext     v6.16b, v6.16b, v6.16b, #8 // aligns top 8 bytes over bottom 8 bytes  
    pmull   v7.8h, v2.8b, v1.8b        // uses a copy of v0.8 also shifted by 8 bytes
    ext     v2.16b, v2.16b, v2.16b, #8
    pmull   v6.8h, v6.8b, v4.8b
    pmull   v2.8h, v2.8b, v5.8b
```

Working on uint8x16_t or uint16x8_t does not matter -- and this seems to be a recurring theme of clang avoiding the top bits of a register to be accessed. I haven't found a `-mtune=cortex-73` kind of an option that would force a different code generation, so I could at least assess if this is generally less performant (which I expect it to be on little cores). **ARM64 gcc works as expected.**

This may not matter (except for size wise and having less registers allocated) if the `ext` instructions are known to double-issue with `pmull` where as two `pmull`s would not.

Comment: I suppose this might just be a missed optimisation in the compiler.

Comment: It seems very likely worse for front-end throughput if tuning for a core with out-of-order exec.  The front-end can get later instructions into the back-end sooner while the back-end is chewing on the `pmull`/2 instructions.  This looks like a missed optimization, not something where we should make excuses for clang's code-gen.

Comment: Why not to put this part into `inline asm(...)` then ?

Comment: @user3124812: that might be an option. Historically I've avoided inline assembler (thus being extremely rusty on it) as I have needed to compile with ICC and MSVC in addition to clang and gcc. But maybe it's possible to restrict the use to the absolute minimum.

Comment: It's not an option: `int8x16_t foo(int8x16_t a) { asm("add %0, %1, %1" :  "=w"(a) : "0"(a)); return a; }` is something I'd like to accomplish, but all constraints 'a-zA-Z' give errors. The traditional way seems to pass memory addresses in generic purpose registers, then load to vector registers and write back to memory. This is not what I'm going to do.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: It can be done with a little tweaking.  The `%0` operands in your example expand to `v0`, so you can write `"add %0.16b, %1.16b, %1.16b"`.  https://godbolt.org/z/zKPzzcEM1  Also useful to note for ARM64 float or SIMD inline assembly are the [template modifiers](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_ccb1517569488757.htm), AFAIK supported (but not documented) by both gcc and clang.

Comment: An issue has been added: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/52868